# Смена иконки приложения

Tags: windows, иконки, winapi, c++, icon

У меня есть приложение, которое может **менять свою иконку**, которую берет из ресурсов вшитых в ехе файл. Реализовано это через вызов win api

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, icon_handle);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, icon_handle);
```

и все работало нормально, иконка менялась в таскбаре на Windows 7. Но когда я установил его на другу машину с темже Windows 7, иконка вдруг перестала меняться, хотя сама загрузка иконки происходила успешно. И оказалось что если выставить в настройках таскбара **"never combine"**, то иконка изменяется на корректную и все работает как надо. И вот собственно вопрос - почему **таскбар в режиме** **"combine"** запоминает одну иконку и **не обновляет** ее?
И кстати если переименовать приложение или просто изменить путь к нему, иконка используется корректная.

Comment: Это стандартное поведение таскбара. Если вы запустите несколько экземпляров приложения и каждое из них изменит иконку на другую, то что должна установить windows на таскбаре?!

Comment: Я запускаю только один экземпляр приложения, и у него иконка не обновляется вообще, остается начальной. Если я перенесу ехе в другую папку и запущу приложение снова иконка будет обновляться как надо. Но ехе по старому пути по прежнему работает не корректно.

Comment: Пробовал удалить файл IconCache.db, перезагрузился и всеравно тоже самое

Comment: Давайте пойдем от противного. Вообще зачем понадобилось менять иконку приложения? Честно говоря, по названию ветки мне изначально показалось, что автор не умеет работать с редактором ресурсов, благо в нем можно выставить приложению любую иконку. Причем в разных форматах (от 8х8 до 64х64 для различных видов отображения).

Но если задача состоит именно в том, что программа должна в процессе работы менять свою пиктограмму... Эм... Может опять же дело в том, что нет иконки нужного размера в ресурсах?

Comment: Икона в режиме "never combine" меняется, и там используется точно такой же размер иконки как и "combine".
Все иконки имеют одинаковый набор размеров, от 16х16 до 64х64
Загружаю я их так

    //Resource.h
    #define IDI_FIRST_ICON 100
    #define IDI_SECOND_ICON 100
    //Resource.rc
    IDI_FIRST_ICON  ICON   "..\Icon\First.ico"
    IDI_SECOND_ICON  ICON  "..\Icon\Second.ico"
    

Притом на моей машине все работает, иконки загружаются и меняются как надо. Проблема только когда я ставлю это приложение на другую машину.

Comment: @German, тогда посмотрите [ссылочку][1]. Windows генерирует некий уникальный идентификатор программы по названию exeшника. Вам вероятно имеет смысл его поменять по методу описанному в статье.

[1]:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/08/20/10341464.aspx

Answer (score 1):

В комментариях  я писал

> нашел функцию SHChangeNotify,
> которая якобы должна уведомить таскбар
> об изменениях

Тогда я не правильно ее использовал вызывая - `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_FLUSH, NULL, NULL)`. Исправил на `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, NULL, NULL);` и иконка обновилась. Возможно это не лучшее решение, но оно сработало.